# How to increase login session timeout?

Tags: php

**Question:**
How to increase login session timeout?

**Situation:**
I have a login script in PHP that connects to a MYSQL database. Right now a login session lasts for about 24 hours. But I want this to be *2 weeks*. So I want my users to have to login again after 2 weeks. Again, right now a user has to re-login after about 24 hours. I haven't been able to measure this precisely. But I always have to re-login the next day. What I also should mention is that I have closed the browser and even restarted the computer to see if I'm still logged in the same day. And yes, the login session is still intact. But the next day this session is gone.

**Code used but did not work:**

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 1209600);
session_set_cookie_params(1209600);
session_start();
```

I noticed when looking at my php.ini file that mysqlnd read timeout lasts for exactly 24 hours. So I also added the following code to the code above:

```
ini_set('mysqlnd.net_read_timeout', 1209600);
```

But this all doesn't make any difference. I also tried the following code that I found on codeleaks.io. I added the following code in my login script:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['start'] = time();
$_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (60);
```

And the following code on my landing page after logging in:

```
$currentTime = time();
if($currentTime > $_SESSION['expire']) {
session_unset();
session_destroy();
}
```

I set 60 seconds just to see if it works. And indeed, this works. Session will expire after 60 seconds. But when I want this session to last more than 24 hours then it doesn't work. So something else is destroying the session. I can't figure out what it is. I hope one of you guys can help me. Please note that I'm just an amateur.

Comment: Is your script the only one running on the system, or are you in a shared hosting environment or something? If the latter - is each user (on the server, not talking about your website users) using their own directory to store session files? If not, and you share one with others, then there is a good chance that _their_ shorter garbage collection interval clears up your session files as well.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your comment. Can I see in my php.ini file if it is shared?

Comment: If you are on a shared hosting platform (or some other sort of setup, where you shre resources with multiple users), then `session.save_path` should point to a user-specific folder. If it just says `/tmp` or something, then you can likely assume that all users share it.

Comment: I found this `session.save_path 2;/var/tmp` So this is a shared hosting platform?

Comment: _"So this is a shared hosting platform?"_ - no, not necessarily. I said _if_ it was, and the save dir is set to the same folder for all users, this could explain your problem. But we can't tell if it _is_ a shared platform, just from the fact that it is set to this path. Why/how do you not _know_ whether you are on shared hosting?

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for clarifying. But probably this is not shared as I have my own hosting and domain and SSL etc.

Comment: _"and domain and SSL etc."_ - that has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with whether you are using shared hosting or not.

Comment: I would suggest instead of changing php.ini at a run time please change it directly on a machine.

Answer (score -2):

To increase the login session timeout in PHP, you can use the session_set_cookie_params() function to set the lifetime of the session cookie. This function takes two parameters: the lifetime of the cookie in seconds, and the path on the server in which the cookie will be available. For example, to set the session timeout to 2 hours, you can use the following code:

```
$lifetime = 7200;
session_set_cookie_params($lifetime);
session_start();
```

This will set the session cookie to expire after 2 hours (7200 seconds) of inactivity.

Alternatively, you can also set the session timeout using ini_set() function

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 7200);
session_start();
```

Please note that you need to call session_start() after setting the parameters to take effect

Comment: Have you _read_ the question ...? Both these things you are suggesting, they said they already tried.

Comment: @jDoe Thanks for your answer, but I have already tried this. Please check my code.